# How to generate a sound has 32bit resolution and 96kHz sampling rate

Tags: dac, sound

I'am looking for a mcu which has enhanced DAC performance to generate a sound which has some features (32bit BD / 96kHz SR) but i couldn't cause of bitdept.
Are there any mcu which are capable to do these requirements ?  or Using external DAC is better way ?

Comment: Why wouldn't 24-bit do? If you can find an external DAC of that depth, then yes, although at that depth the noise performance requires all sorts of special board design considerations ...

Comment: "32bit BD" - why do you need this?

Comment: In general, MCUs don't have this kind of audio DACs built in. The MCU is usually connected to an external audio DAC that can perform this job much better.

Comment: @pjc50 because competing products is met these requirements. I know up to these bits 24, 32 unnecessary but i want to design smt. as they did.

Comment: @BruceAbbott  because competing products is met these requirements. I wonder that how they achieved to do like this.

Comment: @Justme what kinda problems might be occur in case of up to these bit levels.

Comment: Which 'competing' products are you talking about?

Comment: vehicle acustic systems like engine sound @BruceAbbott

Comment: It seems to me that you are naively misunderstanding the weasel words from the marketing department of a competitor.

Comment: Why stop at just 32 ? Why not go full analog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you see a DAC chip rated for "32 bit" what this actually means is that it will accept 32 bit digital samples on its digital input, and it could imply that the internal digital filter would have more bit depth than a competing DAC accepting 24 bit samples, resulting in lower rounding error during oversampling and filtering... although the latter is implied, if you want to be sure, check the specs.

Now, if the analog output had SNR or THD+N at the 32-bit level this would mean 192 dB SNR/THD+N, and that ain't gonna happen in practice. Think about it, with 3V full scale, one LSB would be 0.7 nanovolts... If you want to know the actual analog performance, check the datasheet.

You can estimate an "effective number of bits" \$ ENOB = log_2 10^\frac{SNR in dB}{20} \$. For example 96dB SNR results in ENOB of 16 bits, although a signal of a lower amplitude than 1LSb can be played back with dithering.

In other words, it's in large part marketing glitter. It is nice to write "32-bit DAC chip" on the brochure, even if analog performance in terms of SNR and THD+N is only at the 14-bit level!.... They ARE using a "32-bit" DAC chip after all, so it's not a lie!

Comment: thanks a lot ! i had to think this.

Answer (score 2):

The bitness of an audio DAC might only mean the bitness of audio interface so it has has very little to do with its analog performance. You won't find a 32 bit DAC with 192 dB analog performance, or a 24 bit DAC with 144 dB analog performance. A 24 bit DAC with 132 dB performance however is available, from many manufacturers, and some go close to 140 dB.